# What is "what and that... and "to leave someone to", and "the opening"? Driving a car

Tags: word-meaning

The text is about how to drive a car

> 1) Think of your car as a bike.  The back wheels rotate in one straight line no matter **what and that** leaves you to adjust the direction of the front wheels to wherever you want to go.

And in the following I haven't understood the meaning of "opening" wheather it is a door side of driver or space where you are parking in or both. thanks a lot!

> 2) In order to **parallel park** between two cars
>
> > a. Pull up next to the cars just far enough so that the back of your car is parallel to ***the side of the opening*** closest to you.
> >
> > b. Shift your gear into Reverse gear and steer the car in the opposite direction in which the cars are parked.
> >
> > c. Slowly back **into the opening**, using your rear and side view mirrors, and stop as soon as your car is halfway into the opening.
> >
> > d. Shift your gear so that you are now in the Drive mode and steer your car back to the direction of the parked cars.

Comment: These instruction are **incorrect**, in 2.b you should steer **towards** the curb (or where the other cars are parked) to back into the parking space.  In 2.a, "the side of the open **parking spot**".  If you know how to drive, you will know what the instructions mean.

Comment: and 2.d is delirium?

Comment: The instructions in 2) make little sense to me.  I wouldn't want the author to be telling me how to land the plane when the pilot has passed out.  And doesn't a bicycle have one rear wheel? :)

Comment: I think 2a-2d is an attempt at describing how to parallel park (which wasn't very successful, in my humble opinion). The four-step instruction can be easily found on the web, e.g., [one on Wimbledon Driving School's website](http://www.wimbledondrivingschool.com/how-to-parallel-park/).

Comment: "The opening" refers to the space between cars in which you want to put your car.  The instructions are not very well-written, though; I wonder if the author was not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 2):

The word ***and*** is a **conjunction** that separates two **clauses** in a **compound sentence**. The first clause:

> The back wheels rotate in one straight line no matter what

**No matter what** means "always" or "despite anything else happening". In this case, it means that the back wheels on a car cannot rotate independently.

> that leaves you to adjust the direction of the front wheels to wherever you want to go.

**That leaves you** is a clumsy way to say "you are therefore able to" steer with the front wheels of the car. It is related to "you are left to" or "it remains to", which essentially means that in the absence of *x*, you can do *y*; it is idiomatic.

To your second question, **the opening** refers to the open parking space where you intend to park.